# Override or prevent AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I read quite a few articles about overriding directive but I didn't find a way to correctly prevent a directive from being executed.

Actually I'm using ionic framework, and I'd to like to prevent the default select directive to be executed since it doesn't work on a Microsoft surface...

Any Idea how to do this ?

Ty.

Comment: what do you mean, the default select directive doesn't work on a Microsoft Surface? Is this something that is documented somewhere, or is in the bug track for angular?

Comment: I think something else is probably going on here, since the surface runs Internet Explorer 11 which is fully compatible with all angular directives.  Instead of asking how to disable something that is built in, you should be asking why the code you wrote to use the feature isn't working correctly.  I doubt there is any issue with the specific hardware you are trying to use.

Comment: @Claies as I wrote I'm using ionic and since version 1.0.0-beta.14 the select doesn't work on surface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is an idea :

```
module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('selectDirective', function($delegate) {
    return {};
  });
}])
```

Although it would break the native < select > element, so you might want to disable parts of your directives like this:

```
module.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('selectDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    directive.template = '';
    return directive;
  });
}])
```